# JSON-Fortran API shows warning when using json_module

Tags: json, fortran, gfortran, gcc-warning

I created a configuration module which loads a config file `config.json` thanks to the JSON-Fortran API given by jacobswilliams https://github.com/jacobwilliams/json-fortran and I get a quite boring warning in all my project.

When I use the module like this :

```
module ConfigModule
   use :: json_module, ck => json_ck
   implicit none
```

I get the following warning for this module and all files using `ConfigModule` :

```
Warning: Only array FINAL procedures declared for derived type 'json_file' defined at (1), suggest also scalar one [-Wsurprising]
```

I'm using gfortran 6.3

Does someone know how to resolve this ?

Comment: What resolution do you want? You can suppress the warning by doing what it suggests, or by not using `-Wsurprising`.

Comment: I would like to fix the problem instead of suppress the warning by removing all surprising warnings. The thing is I don't understand the problem and I think it's inside the library.